# How can I get these promises to resolve in order

Tags: firebase, vue.js, promise, vuex

I am having issues with firebase promise chains resolving before the entire chain is completed.  I have a login and signup modal that displays errors to the user when necessary.  I building this with VUEJs

If the error is something like bad email formatting the promise chain works perfectly and displays the correct error message to the user.  When the formatting is correct and the request is actually sent to fire base, the .then will fire before the initial firebase promise is fully resolved causing my if in the signup method statement to always resolve to false, and redirecting to /dashboard before the error gets back to the app from firebase.

I have poked at this thing for a few hours now.  I have tried reorganizing the promise chain.  I have a login in component that is having the exact same behavior.

Here is my method that fires when the signup button is clicked.

```
computed:{
    error () {
      return this.$store.getters.error
    }
},
methods: {
  signup () {
      const userProfile = {
        userName: this.userName,
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
        password: this.password,
        birthDate: this.birthDate,
        address: this.address,
        city: this.city,
        state: this.state,
        zip: this.zip,
        email: this.email
      }
      if (this.email && this.password && this.userName) {
        this.$store.dispatch('signUserUp', userProfile)
          .then( () => {
            if (this.error) {
              console.log(this.error)
              return this.feedback = this.error.message
            } else {
                return this.$router.replace('/dashboard')
            }
        })
      } else {
        return this.feedback = 'Please enter all required fields'
      }
    }
}
```

This is action in my Vuex store the method dispatches to

```
signUserUp({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setLoading', true)
      commit('clearError')
      let slug = null
      let newUser = {}
      let newError = {
        test: 'test',
        message: 'User Name is already taken, please chose another.'
      }
      slug = slugify(payload.userName, {
      replacement: '-',
      remove: /[$*_=~.()''!\-:@]/g,
      lower: true
      })
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + slug).once('value', snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
          console.log('name exists')
          commit('setError', newError)
        } else {
          console.log('user does not exist')
          firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
          .then(
            cred => {
                newUser = {
                userId: cred.user.uid,
                userName: slug,
                firstName: payload.firstName,
                lastName: payload.firstName,
                birthDate: payload.birthDate,
                adress: payload.adress,
                city: payload.city,
                state: payload.state,
                zip: payload.zip,
                email: payload.email
              }
              console.log(newUser)
              commit('setUser', newUser)
              console.log('sign up complete')
              firebase.database().ref('/users/' + slug).set(newUser)
                .then( () => {
                commit('setLoading', false)
                console.log('user profile uploaded')
              })
              .catch( error => {
                console.log(error)
              })
            }
          )
          .catch(
            error => {
              commit('setLoading', false)
              commit('setError', error)
              console.log(error)
            }
          )
        }
      })
    }
```

What I am trying to do is check against the database to make sure the username is not already taken.  If it has been taken I want to show the user the the error and stay at the signup form.  If not, i want it to create the new account, upload the profile to my real time database, and then redirect to /dashboard if everything is successful.

This is my first do it 100% myself app, so please be gentle lol.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [the documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions), `signUserUp` should return a promise, in order for to chain it with `this.$store.dispatch('signUserUp', userProfile).then(...)`. Firebase supports promises where possible. It's possible to chain `once()` and flatten promise chain with `async..await`:

```
async function signUserUp({commit}, payload) {
  try {
    ...  
    const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref('users/' + slug).once('value');
    ...
    const cred = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password);
    ...
  } catch (error) {
    commit('setLoading', false)
    commit('setError', error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow that was so much more simple than I had pictured in my head.  It works beautifully now.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to [wait on the asynchronous code in your action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions) to complete then your action should return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Probably the simplest way* to make this work with your current code is to wrap it in a new `Promise`.

```
signUserUp({commit}, payload) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        /* existing function body */
    });
}
```

Then add calls to `resolve()` when the asynchronous code has completed. (For example, at this point: `console.log('user profile uploaded')` or after one of the errors.) Once you call the resolve callback it will invoke the `then` handler in your signup method. You can reject the `Promise` as well using the reject callback. In your case however it looks like you want the action to handle the error itself and not propagate it.

*Since it looks like the firebase API uses promises you could also attempt to return the result of the firebase functions.